# why rawQuery is working and query isn't working?

Tags: android

I am using query for search but i don't understand why one code is work and another one not work ?!

this is working:

```
          String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Soras
                               +" WHERE "+KEY_SoraName+" LIKE '%"+soraName+"%'";
          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
```

but this isn't get any result:

```
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Soras, new String[]{
             KEY_SORA_NO, KEY_SoraName}, KEY_SoraName + "=?",
            new String[]{soraName}, null, null, null, null);*/
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: the second one doesn't get any result.

Comment: Basically they are not the same queries!

Comment: Basically in second query you are asking where `KEY_SoraName = soraName` not using like so you will get result only if they are equal.

Comment: yes that's right in the database there is some spaces after the word so like is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in second case `%` is not appended into value and you didn't add `LIKE` clause into query. You need to use this:

```
KEY_SoraName + " like ?", new String[] {"%" +soraName + "%"} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_QuranSoras, new String[]{
             KEY_SORA_NO, KEY_SoraName}, KEY_SoraName+" LIKE '%"+soraName+"%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = your_database.query(MY_TABLE, new String[] {"first_column","second_column"},your_column + " LIKE '%"+your_criteria+"%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Try something like this and it will probably work!